# Returning a value to a SNMP server via a shell script

Tags: shell, snmp

Hello my dear coder friends, I have an hard problem to solve.
Me trying to create a SNMP server that tells the status of a physical device. Status of this device is stored in Redis database.

I am using the following .sh for retrieving device status:

```
tempratureStatus=$(redis-cli get tempratureStatus)
echo "Temperature Status: $tempratureStatus"
if [ "$tempratureStatus" = "True" ]; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi;
```

This script returns whether the device is over heated or not. I am also using following conf file to call this .sh script with SNMP server (see the very last `extend postgresfile` line):

```
rwuser bootstrap priv
rwuser demo priv
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
sysServices    72
proc  mountd
proc  ntalkd    4
proc  sendmail 10 1
disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%
load   12 10 5
trapsink     localhost public
iquerySecName   internalUser       
rouser          internalUser
defaultMonitors          yes
linkUpDownNotifications  yes
extend postgresfiles /etc/snmp/scripts/battleshort_local.sh
```

However, when I use the command,

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.1.106 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."postgresfiles".1'
```

I get the following Error:

```
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."postgresfiles".1 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

Whats the problem here I can figure it out. Am I returning undefined? Or am I even returning something?

Comment: why do you have a newline in the object identifier?

Comment: Sorry I guess that was part of my mistake. Now the response is changed to :

NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."postgresfiles".1 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

Comment: I edited the question accordingly, glad for your help @glennjackman

Comment: BTW, removing comments and blank lines from the config file is in accordance with the "Minimal" part of [mcve] guidance. To really do it right, any line not necessary for the problem to be reproduced should also be removed as well (see also "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why do you have the `.1`?